# Mobile Site Forums

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, forums, mobile-website

We have planned to implement Mobile site for our company. We are developing our mobile site using the ASP.NET MVC 3 and JQuery Mobile.

We are going to integrate Forums in mobile site?. Is any examples forum hosted in Mobile site ?/ Any open source forum available for mobile site ?

Thanks,
Velu

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://northamerica.msteched.com/topic/details/DPR304?fbid=BKTyC3bXZXM&mtag=mbar-email#showdetails) is a very good demo from teched about mobile integration.

I also know that the Nerd Dinner and Music Store demos on asp.net have mobile integration tutorials that would be worth reviewing.